# How do I open Spesific Settings in Android Java

Tags: java, android

Here is my code, the closest I can see to getting to the settings where I want (CA Cert) is opening settings search. However, I cannot programmatically pass in a search phrase but ideally, I would like to open Settings Ca Cert.

```
    public void openSettings(View v){
    Intent openSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_SIM_PROFILES_SETTINGS);
    //openSettings.putExtra("Search Phrase","Ca Certificate")
    this.startActivity(openSettings);
     }
```